# Chunking text by character length AND word-boundary in Python

Tags: python, string, twitter, twython

My simple Twitter bot (in Python/Twython) sends tweets from a textfile, line by line. It uses a list comprehension to chunk the (arbitrary length) lines into 140 characters sections and tweet them out as Twitter "threads" (nb not related to os threads).

(Twitter is rolling out an increase in the character limit to 280 currently, but the issue will remain, regardless).

While adequate, the comprehension often splits a line mid-word, which is unsatisfactory.

This is the list comprehension:

```
tweetlist = [ bigtweet[i:i+140] for i in range(0, len(bigtweet), 140) ]
```

and here is a line > 140 chars:

```
John buttered the toast slowly, deliberately, in the bathroom, with a knife, at midnight. Five professors wrote six papers in March (quickly, under pressure, and inelegantly)
```

In this case, we end up with the line split like this:

```
Five professors wrote six papers in March (quickly, under pressure, and inelegantly).     John buttered the toast slowly, deliberately, in the b

athroom, with a knife, at midnight.
```

What would be better would be to split the line at the nearest space character before the 140 limit.

So in my example text, the lines would be better like this (split at the space before "bathroom"):

```
Five professors wrote six papers in March (quickly, under pressure, and inelegantly). John buttered the toast slowly, deliberately, in the 

bathroom, with a knife, at midnight.
```

Note that this is *not* about parsing/splitting into whole sentences (there are a few helpful threads here already on that). The data I'm actually using is not consistent in sentence structure, punctuation or spacing, so there will be "inelegant" splits whatever I do, and ending up with a small proportion of those is perfectly acceptable.

I'm guessing that one way to proceed would be to chunk, then test each chunk to see if it terminates in a space char, and if it doesn't, iteratively chunk again reducing the chunk by n chars until it tests True.

I can probably fumble my way through doing that, but I am wondering if there are alternative methods?

NB I am *not* a programmer, and I've built my bot from code examples I found here and elsewhere plus bits and bobs of code I've added. The comprehension was suggested by another SO member, but I can generally understand code and can manage a bit of original code myself. What I simply don't understand yet are OO methods/classes. I'm using Python 2.7 on Linux, but can move to Python 3 easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the text into words using a space. Then count words until the `max_tweet` length is reached. Join the words back together using a space. This is easily done using a Python generator function as follows:

```
def get_tweet(text, max_tweet=140):
    total = 0
    start_index = 0
    words = text.split(' ')

    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if total + len(word) > max_tweet:
            tweet = ' '.join(words[start_index : index])
            yield tweet
            total = 0
            start_index = index

        total += len(word) + 1

    if start_index != index:
        tweet = ' '.join(words[start_index:])
        yield tweet


text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh."

for tweet in get_tweet(text):
    print len(tweet), tweet
```

This example text would be split as follows:

```
137 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
138 magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat
134 massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis
138 vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
139 eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat
135 a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur
139 ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet
133 adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt
138 tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed
31 fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
```

Note, this could fail if there is text longer than `140` without a space.

When called with `get_tweet(text, 240)`:

```
237 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
239 eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
233 tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus
237 viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper
240 libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet
80 orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split your text into words and join them back together again:

```
bigtweet = 'John buttered the toast slowly, deliberately, in the bathroom, with a knife, at midnight. Five professors wrote six papers in March (quickly, under pressure, and inelegantly)'

def yield_tweets(words):
    length, offset, tweet = 0, 0, []
    for word in words:
        if (len(word) + length - offset - 1) >= 140:
            yield ' '.join(tweet)
            tweet = []
            offset = length
        length += len(word) + 1
        tweet.append(word)
    yield ' '.join(tweet)

for tweet in yield_tweets(bigtweet.split()):
    print(tweet)
```

output:

```
John buttered the toast slowly, deliberately, in the bathroom, with a knife, at midnight. Five professors wrote six papers in March
(quickly, under pressure, and inelegantly)
```

**Update:**

```
lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh."
for tweet in yield_tweets(lorem.split()):
    print(len(tweet),tweet)
```

output:

```
137 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
138 magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat
134 massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis
138 vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
139 eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat
135 a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur
139 ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet
133 adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt
138 tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed
31 fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
```